# Rolling Minimum with Fixed Window

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I'm looking for help calculating a cumulative minimum within a rolling window of a fixed length. I have a variable in a dataset, and I'd like to create a new variable that looks at each of the last three observations in my variable, and outputs the minimum.

```
existing.variable <- c(1, 2, 3, 5, 3, 2, 3)    
desired.target <- c(NA, NA, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2)
dat <- data.frame(existing.variable, desired.target)
```

Comment: Have you tried `rollapply` from `zoo` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about speed and don't mind a `base` approach, you could do:

```
window_var <- 3

data$desired.target <- c(rep(NA, window_var - 1), 
                         sapply(1:(nrow(data) - window_var + 1), 
                                function(x) min(data$existing.variable[x:(x + window_var - 1)])))
```

First part is setting you window which will be applied, in the second part you construct a vector which fills first rows with NA, and then dynamically looks for minimum with `sapply`.

But that's just for curiosity, probably you're better of with `zoo` as @markus suggested already.

However, rolling functions throughout packages usually operate by referring to rows, and when you have gaps in between (e.g. gaps between dates), you can benefit from `sapply`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Turns out the code I needed was: data$desired.target <- rollapply(data$target.variable, 3, FUN = min, fill =  NA, align = c("right"))